# How to stop autosaving?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, automation

[Is there a notebook autosave frequency configuration?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13997/is-there-a-notebook-autosave-frequency-configuration][1])

I made my MMA file to autosave, it was nice for a little bit. However, now it automatically saves every 10 seconds, and try to save every time I try to evaluate. It slows down or freezes when it auto save.

How do I get rid of the autosave?

Comment: So setting this to `False` doesn't work? Have you done that for the `EvaluationNotebook[]` or for the `$FrontEnd`? Or do you mean the second answer? Check `ScheduledTasks[]`.

Comment: Sorry, can't help without your feedback.

Comment: sorry, i was not in the lab, i will check on monday and let you know, i am sorry!

Comment: No worries. See you on Monday,

Comment: @Kuba I think, False solved the problem. I really apologize for my unconsidered question. it was really simple one! I should think about before I even ask!

Comment: [Related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144688/how-to-stop-autosaving). [This paclet](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/EwanDawson/NotebookAutoSave/) claims to autosave every 10 seconds instead of every evaluation.  Currently, the 10 second threshold is hard-coded, but perhaps the author is willing to make it an option. 
 If not, one could download [the source code](https://github.com/EwanDawson/NotebookAutoSave), make the change, and install it locally.