# Automatic backup on Mathematica

Tags: notebooks

When there’s a power outage and I’ve done a lot of work on Mathematica, I lose all the informations. Is there a setup on Mathematica to make an **automatic backup**. Knowing that on "wolfram cloud" does it.
Thank you, you will save me!

Comment: Have you read [How do I enable autosaving in a Mathematica notebook?](https://support.wolfram.com/34680?src=mathematica)

Comment: Another thing you can do is save frequently and at the same time use an app that makes separate copies each time you do save. On macOS, the app Forever Save 2 does that.

Comment: @Jason B  Thank you for me and all those who had the same problem. I never see these options, I think their location on the menu format is wrong. It would state on the File menu or Evaluation, I would have seen them. Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: I think you'll have problems with that.  Often, when making changes to a notebook, you don't want to save them until you're sure they are what you want;  not infrequently, just easier to start over from the point of last save.  I personally have found it most useful to simply save my work periodically during the day and usually I'll do so with a new file name.

Comment: @JasonB. Your comment should be an answer. Alternatively, this question can be seen as "answered in the documentation."

Comment: Note that @JasonB. 's answer will not be a good solution for everyone.  That tells Mathematica to autosave after *every evaluation*.  This will be bad if (1) you prefer to keep the old versions outside of crashes or (2) your mathematica files get even a little bit large and the constant autosaving slows everything down (there is no option for setting the autosave frequency): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144688/how-to-stop-autosaving

Comment: Also (3) if you do a lot of writing between evaluations that you don't want to use.  [Related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144688/how-to-stop-autosaving).

Answer (score 2):

EwanDawson's : [NotebookAutoSave paclet](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/EwanDawson/NotebookAutoSave/) claims to autosave every 10 seconds instead of every evaluation.  Currently, the 10 second threshold is hard-coded, but perhaps the author is willing to make it an option.  If not, one could download [the source code](https://github.com/EwanDawson/NotebookAutoSave), make the change, and install it locally.  Advice on how to do this installation more quickly/simply would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
 
Format
      Option Inspector
                 Show option values : Global Preferences
                 + NoteBook Option
                    .....File Optiins   x NotebookAutoSave True.
                    Apply.

My problem was that I started a job overnight. In the morning I discovered that the power outlet was not properly engaged on my laptop, it discharged itself by losing the program and even the memory variables that I had calculated. So much the better for me, it will teach me!

I made a small export program and I’m going to use a working copy in automatic.

```
Mylist = {1, 2, 3, 4}; fname = 
 FileNameJoin[{"C:\\tmp\\", "tmp.dat"}]; Export[fname, Mylist];
```

after for recover lost variable :

```
Mylist = Flatten[Import["C:\\tmp\\tmp.dat", "Data"]];Mylist
```