# Set the ClosingSaveDialog to False

Tags: front-end, options, dialog-window

I would like to stop Mathematica from showing the "Save Changes To" dialog whenever I try to close a notebook.
I tried changing this from the Option Inspector by setting the losingSaveDialog -> False
However, for some reason, as soon as I then close the notebook, the dialog still pops up and when I double check, the Open Inspector seem to have changed back to default!?
Is there a way for this to work as expected? I suppose that building a code for this should work, but I do not know how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging, one can adopt a similar code to [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13997/is-there-a-notebook-autosave-frequency-configuration)
and do:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "ClosingAutoSave"] = True
```

For some reason, this does not update the Option Inspector, but otherwise works.

Note: As @b3m2a1 pointed out, the above makes the change permanent, i.e. even exiting and re-entering Mathematica, the value of ClosingAutoSave will still be set on True.
Instead:

```
 CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, "ClosingAutoSave"] = True
```

will only change the setting for the current session.

Comment: Probably safer to do it on `$FrontEndSession` instead of `$FrontEnd`. Doesn't make the changes permanent

Comment: thanks, I updated the answer