# Please help validate autoSave function or refactor for better performance

Tags: front-end, notebooks, date-and-time, save, user-interface

I finally have my `autoSave[]` function that appears to work. Although it does automatically save file the `DateString` (dynamic in-place updating) which provides the interval time to do an `autoSave` does not appear to be consistent. Is this because the frontend will not save file if no edits had taken place since last save? How would you improve `autoSave[]`? But I know it works by making changes to a test file and closing without saving has all edits contained when reopened.

```
autoSave[minutes_ : 10] := 
  Row[{"last autoSave", 
    Dynamic[Refresh[NotebookSave[]; DateString[], 
      UpdateInterval -> minutes 60]]}, " \[Rule] "];
```

Comment: Where's that placed? Because Dynamic does not fire unless visible on the screen. [related: 13997](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13997/5478)

Comment: @Kuba placed in a cell inside an open notebook. it only displays a dynamic evaluated `DateString[]` in an output cell.

Comment: If the cell scrolls away from the screen it stops working. See tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic

Comment: Try placing it in a docked cell so it is always visible.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi  great idea. i tried doing that but the official documentation only confused me. if you feel like it write out steps in an answer and if it works ill tag your answer as accepted and press the up key giving you credit.

Comment: @JulesManson I probably will not have time to do it today. Will get to it over the weekend.