# How to use export and schedule tasks to backup entire contents of an notebook at regular time intervals?

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories, save, dumpsave, scheduledtask

I am sorry I don't have any code to share so I would like your ideas.

Although there is an `AutoSave` feature in Mathematica it lacks usefulness as it cannot be configured to only save at time intervals or after a set number of edits and it completely destroys the very precious `Undo`. Besides you may not want the last iteration of your work if your pc crashes.

Therefore it makes sense to protect your work onto another file at regular time intervals while still manually saving your `EvaluationNotebook[]` (file which you have open) at your discretion.

If I can schedule a regular timed interval backup of say every hour or half hour it is likely I would only need the last iteration so the last save backup should overwrite the previous backup so it doesn't load up a directory with hundreds of junk files.

I have seen some solutions on here that are overly complex or dance around the most direct way that mathematica can likely do this.

How would you suggest going about solving this?

Comment: related: [13997](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13997/5478) - please check answers there