# Why isn't autosave enabled by default?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

While I've come across several ways to implement/enable autosave (see: [Is there a notebook autosave frequency configuration?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13997/is-there-a-notebook-autosave-frequency-configuration), [Saving my code before cell evaluations: Insurance against front end hanging](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8761/saving-my-code-before-cell-evaluations-insurance-against-front-end-hanging/8762#8762), [How can I set up a versioning system within a notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/how-can-i-set-up-a-versioning-system-within-a-notebook)), I've never found a reason why it isn't enabled by default.

It seems incredibly useful to me - surely there must be some good reason why Wolfram chose to leave it unconfigured!

Why isn't autosave enabled by default?

Comment: Sidenote, I just lost a whole notebook to someone else sitting down at unattended computer & mindlessly closing hours of unsaved work. **Grr.**

Comment: Why should it be enabled by default? A feature that's incredibly useful to one person does not mean it's incredibly useful to everyone. It's bad enough that there is no undo in _Mathematica_. No undo + autosave is just nightmare^nightmare. The simple solution is to not let monkeys sit at your desk and make you lose your work. Even simpler is to save your work regularly.

Comment: My curiosity was more along the lines of - is there a specific problem that enabling autosave by default would cause, problematic enough as to justify leaving it disabled? - e.g. automated software updates are sometimes disabled by default because they might break dependent systems.

My computer just died (the second SSD in 4 months), so I'm piggybacking. However much I dislike it, I am still human, and therefore occasionally neglect to regularly save. It's a little bit like nightmare^(nightmare*frustration).

Comment: Yes, auto save removes the ability to choose the "point of save" from the user and places it in the software's hands. I'm not sure if you're actually aware that there is no undo in _Mathematica_. Imagine now if the monkey had instead done Ctrl-A and deleted all contents... Auto save + no undo would've meant you've lost your _entire_ notebook, not just the unsaved changes. You could've done this accidentally as well (it certainly has happened to me). All modern software that autosave or "soft save", support multiple (often unlimited) undo.

Comment: IMO, this is not a good question to pose here. This is something to take up with Wolfram if it is important to you.

Comment: Actually, @rm -rf (an appropriate name for the matter) answered my question quite nicely.

Comment: btw, I've been bitten badly a few times (when starting out with _Mathematica_) by the lack of undo and accidental overwriting + saving and not being able to revert my edits. Nowadays, any notebook that's worth keeping for more than 1 day, I place it under version control (git). I don't commit every few minutes, but say, something like after 5-6 hrs or after the day's work (or sooner, if I've done something substantial). This way, the worst that could happen is I lose 5-6 hrs of work and nothing more.

Comment: @rm-rf Please consider posting your comment "Yes, auto save removes..." as an answer as that is IMHO *the* answer.

Comment: Not only that, but also, saving a large notebook over a network can take a considerable amount of time, during which the front end is essentially frozen. It would be quite annoying if this would happen frequently when one is trying to work.

Comment: Now that multiple undo has been implemented (v10) I believe this question has new merit so I reopened it.  If anyone disagrees with my decision let me know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At Mr. Wizard's urging, I'll post my reasoning for why this is not enabled by default (and should never be, for *Mathematica*):

- *Mathematica* does not have more than 1 undo, period. This is perhaps the single most requested feature since version 1.0. Even that single undo is not well defined — one might expect (from familiarity with *any other* software out there), that a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> would undo the last input character/word, but no, *Mathematica* treats it (approximately) as "Undo everything that was changed in this cell since the last evaluation and last recorded cursor position". This could be anything from 1 character to 10 lines of code. And the best part — there is no redo!
- More importantly, from a design PoV, enabling auto save by default removes the ability to choose the "point of save" from the user and places it in the software's hands, which can often be disastrous. For example, imagine if you were playing an FPS and the game "decided" to auto save just as you got fragged, instead of at that sweet spot you would've chosen, next to all the health and armor...

  Combined with the lack of any ability to undo changes, this effectively means that anything you type in *Mathematica* would be "permanent". While more and more applications (such as Apple's and MS' office suites, Adobe's Creative Suite, etc) are indeed moving towards the "don't worry about saving" approach (since your data is often stored on the cloud, thus necessitating a save or at least, a "soft save"), note that almost all of them support multiple levels of undo.

To avoid running into such problems, you might want to get into a few (good) habits:

- Remember to save your work often. Today it was your friend, but tomorrow it could've been an unexpected power outage and no battery/backup power. You never know when and how you could lose your hard work.
- Make it a point to place your notebooks under version control if you think it will be useful for more than one day. Although [I don't normally recommend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26180/5) placing notebooks under version control, as long as you're using it as a "poor man's backup", it should be fine.
- Try placing your code in packages (which are plain text files) and use a decent text editor to make your changes. This does take a bit of getting used to, but will be helpful in the long run. I personally use vim to do all my editing work, and it gives me an entire undo tree! In other words, I can go back in history and follow a different path of development and cherry pick changes from a previous branch, etc. Combined with a ridiculously large history limit, I can almost always go back to the first day's edit (not that I need to).

  Just to illustrate, here's a few lines from the vim undo tree for one of my files. In theory, I could go back in time 4 weeks ago and redo a change from one of those undos

  [image]

  Most decent editors have similar features, and so unless you need the interactive features of the notebook or the front end, I'd urge you to avoid using it if you can afford to.

Comment: Just FYI, if one really needs a "poorer" man's backup, one could also try saving notebook files in Dropbox or other similar services which keeps a simple version history. For small files (say <25MB) it simply works without difficulty for me.

Comment: Now _this_ is something that I can print in color 36 pt. font, on a nice sheet of 68 pound paper, and take up with Wolfram. Well done.

Answer (score 5):

Try running this for autosaving your notebook at fixed periods. At least this way you will only lose a few minutes of work if you get another crash.

```
save=DynamicModule[{autosaveTime = 1, nb = EvaluationNotebook[]},
 Row[{
   "Autosave every", Spacer[5],
   Row[{
     InputField[Dynamic[autosaveTime], Number, FieldSize -> 1.5], 
     Spacer[3],
     Grid[{
       {Button["\[Wedge]", 
         Module[{autosaveTimex = autosaveTime}, autosaveTimex++; 
          autosaveTime = Max[1, autosaveTimex]], 
         Appearance -> "Palette", ContentPadding -> False, 
         FrameMargins -> 1, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> 20]},
       {Button["\[Vee]", 
         Module[{autosaveTimex = autosaveTime}, autosaveTimex--; 
          autosaveTime = Max[1, autosaveTimex]], 
         Appearance -> "Palette", ContentPadding -> False, 
         FrameMargins -> 1, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> 20]}
       },
      Spacings -> {0, 0}], Spacer[3], "Min"}],
   Spacer[15],
    Button["Start Autosave",
    Module[{autosave},
     RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
     autosave = CreateScheduledTask[{
        NotebookSave[nb]
        }, autosaveTime*60];
     StartScheduledTask[autosave];
     ]],

   Spacer[5],
    Button["Stop Autosave",
    RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]]
    ]
   }]
 ]
```

You can also add it as a docked cell

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 DockedCells -> 
  Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes@save], Background -> Orange, CellMargins -> 0, 
   ShowStringCharacters -> False]]
```

[image]

Comment: it works!!! everyone's else's autosave at timed intervals either only partially worked or didn't work at all. i have a question about `ShowStringCharacters -> False` inside `DockedCells`. What does that do and why is it necessary?