# Saving a notebook before a crash

Tags: notebooks

On the MacBook Pro, Command+S saves the notebook. So, every few minutes, Command+S is invaluable.

What do other folks do? For example, in TexShop, when I compile my LaTeX code, the file is automatically saved. Is there such a feature for notebook and/or cell evaluation? What are my options?

It's pretty horrible if you haven't saved your work and Mathematica crashes. This is certainly something I would want to share with my students as well.

Comment: Look up `NotebookAutoSave`…

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26740/why-isnt-autosave-enabled-by-default and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/how-can-i-set-up-a-versioning-system-within-a-notebook

Comment: For those using Windows, if the Front End is acting up due to the kernel's unhappiness processing something, you can often terminate the *kernel* manually via Task Manager such that the Front End starts responding again, allowing you to save your Notebook.  Just be careful not to terminate *Mathematica* itself, but just the kernel, or the whole process of salvaging the Front End is lost.