# What syntax refers to "this notebook" object?

Tags: notebooks, options, education

I want a notebook to automatically save after any cell is evaluated. I found that I should use the command

```
SetOptions[XXX, NotebookAutoSave -> True]
```

to do that, where `XXX` should be referring to the current notebook. Unfortunately, I have been searching the web for half an hour now and was not able to find the command which refers to "this notebook". I tried `$FrontEndSession`, `$FrontEnd` and even `$Notebooks` and nothing helped. Therefore, my question is:

What refers to "this notebook" within the `SetOptions` command?

Comment: `EvaluationNotebook[ ]`?

Comment: @Dr.belisarius If I exectue `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave -> True]`, write a new cell afterwards and exectue it, the file stays unsaved.

Comment: `nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave -> True];
Options[nb, NotebookAutoSave]`  Returns `True`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius The problem is, it only saves if at least one cell in the notebook has no semicolon, so that an output is produced. If the output of all cells is suppressed with semicolons, and I write a new cell suppressed with semicolon - an evaluation will not save the file.

Comment: That is exactly by design: `NotebookAutoSave is a notebook option which specifies whether the notebook should automatically be saved after each piece of output generated by evaluation in it. `

Comment: Oh, I see, OK! Thank you! Your solution `EvaluationNotebook[ ]` works.

Comment: If a function doesn't produce output it doesn't make sense to save the file at that point as nothing will have changed (output suppressed by a semicolon is not invisibly written in the file; it's simply not there, it's only present in the kernel).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries When I edit a notebook through the front end, I expect Mathematica to realize that the notebook has been changed. If it does not do that and stores all actions in the Kernel only, it is doing something wrong in my opinion.

Comment: We're talking about autosaving based on *finishing an evaluation*, not editing. If the evaluation doesn't produce output then also manually saving would not store your result as there isn't anything added to the FrontEnd.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries OK. I am mostly interested in saving input lines $\textit{before}$ the evaluation even starts, since they can get lost if a calculation hangs up the computer and I have to do a hard restart.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Oh! I asked about that some time ago http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8761/193

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[]; 
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave -> True]; 
Options[nb, NotebookAutoSave]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Note that the notebook should have a name, i.e., it should have been saved before.

Comment: and your computer should be turned on .)

Comment: and, if based in Argentine, make sure to set-up an emergency power unit.