# How to effectively diff a notebook?

Tags: notebooks

How to effectively diff a notebook with another version of it?   This is usually needed/encountered in revision control, but can be generally useful.   What i currently do is disable notebook history, use less styling, and diff them as text files.

Comment: Some relevant answers [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11258/134).

Comment: Yeah, I'd say it's a duplicate.

Comment: This might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778007/695132

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The old `` AuthorTools` `` package has a `NotebookDiff` function.  You can open the package's documentation like this:

```
NotebookOpen@FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "Applications", 
 "AuthorTools", "Documentation", "English", "AuthorToolsGuide.nb"}];
```

This function is also included in the undocumented `` NotebookTools` `` context (in version 8 at least).  You can simply evaluate

```
NotebookTools`NotebookDiff[]
```

which will pop up a file chooser dialog, or you can pass the two notebooks to it as an argument (either file names or notebook handles, such as the ones returned by `Notebooks[]`).  Please also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774123/steps-to-compare-notebooks-in-workbench/8778007#8778007) of mine.

Access to this diff functionality is included in several of the Tortoise version control clients on Windows.  [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) and [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) are both set up by default to diff Mathematica notebooks this way (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8313379/695132)).

Comment: To be clear: the output of `NotebookTools\`NotebookDiff[]` should be sent to `CreateDocument[]`, i.e., `CreateDocument@NotebookTools\`NotebookDiff[]`.  This will render the diff output in a nice readable form.

Answer (score 2):

Copy as Input Text and paste into [Quick Diff Online](http://www.quickdiff.com/) works very well. As previously described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6530538/879601).

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to use some of the techniques that the experts here provided when I asked [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13312/visualizing-the-difference-between-two-sequences-strings) before.

```
notebook1 = 
  StringJoin[
   Import["/Users/cormullion/Desktop/hex-chart.nb", "Plaintext"]];
notebook2 = 
  StringJoin[
   Import["/Users/cormullion/Desktop/hex-chart-a.nb", "Plaintext"]];
sa = SequenceAlignment[notebook1, notebook2];
Row@Flatten[
  sa /. {a_, b_} :> {Style[a, Red], "(", Style[b, Green], ")"}]
```

giving something looking like this:

[image: dodgy screen grab]

Red shows deletions, green shows additions. Perhaps the parentheses are not ideal for this application...! You can tell that I changed the base from 16 to 12 in the second version of the notebook. Although I used this solution, there's a better built-in but undocumented one found by ace spelunker @rm-rf which you could play with.