# What is the best way to compare two notebooks?

Tags: notebooks, documentation

I have two quite large notebooks with minimal differences. To compare them, I currently put them side by side and compare with my eyes, which feels quite inefficient. What are better ways to do this?

I have done some searching but only found questions from 8/9 years ago, they didn't work for me. In Mathmatica 12 I could not find a function like "Notebookdiff" and I also do not use Wolfram Workbench.

Comment: Mathematica notebooks are filled with formatting and meta data so comparing the `.nb`-Files in a text editor might be quite difficult. One possibility would be to export the two notebooks as `.txt` which should work fine for input and output cells containing text. Comparing those files with a text editor might be an option depending on what kind of content is in the notebooks.The underlying problem here is the same one preventing versioning tools (git,...) from working efficiently/properly.

Comment: At least closely related: [How to effectively diff a notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14286/5478) see also: https://github.com/JP-Ellis/mathematica-notebook-filter

Comment: @Kuba Thats one of the old questions I was referring to - the github project you are linking looks interesting, but it hasn't been updated in a while and according to the CI Pipeline it's broken.

Comment: Since you didn't link them let me leave them. There were talks about ``GitLink`NotebookDiff`` but that package is not evolving too fast on GitHub.