# Extracting notebook history programmatically

Tags: programming, notebooks, cells

I know there is a way to open Notebook history dialogbox using **Cell > Notebook History**, but since there can be a lot of history the dialog box can run very slowly with lags. Is there a way to get a list of last, say, 100 actions done in a notebook programmatically. Since a Mathematica notebook is able to reference itself, I am quite sure there must be a way. Can somebody please help me.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a small example:

```
Labeled @@@ MaximalBy[
    {Max[{CurrentValue[#, CellChangeTimes], 0}], #} & /@ Cells[nb]
   , First,
   10
] // TimelinePlot
```

[image]

Does this fit your needs?

Comment: is there a way i can see exactly what was changed or see the cell prior to change?

Comment: @user13892 I don't think so, but I may be wrong. You'd have to setup a versioning system first. See: [6435](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6435/5478) or https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink